# OpenGraph stories review process confusion

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

So we have a huge eCommerce website that gets a huge traffic and we are integrating Facebook's OpenGraph on it so people can share their experiences/actions on the site such as:

1. After a successful purchase (NAME bought an item on APP).
2. After adding an item to a wish list (NAME added an item to a wish list on APP).
3. After writing a product/customer review (NAME reviewed an item on APP).

I'm still confused on the process of reviewing these actions by Facebook.

Should we go live and then submit the stories for review, or this should be done on our development platform before we launch it to our users? And how would Facebook test it on our development platform?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the open graph in the live website. You can keep your application in the development mode till the application is approved.

[image]

While your application is in development mode, nobody but the administrators/developers/testers/test users can do posting and everything. For rest, the API calls will not be successful.

So you just have to do this- complete the og integration, create a test user-

[image]

test the complete flow and submit for the review explaining the steps with the test user. They will test it with the same test user and will approve it if everything is fine. Then, you can switch your application to [live]. That's it.

Hope it helps. Good luck!